# remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: heroku error while hosting a discord bot

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

i wanted to host my discord bot on heroku

[i have followed and youtube video till here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPvg9bndP1U)

but i don't know what to do to fix this error

full

```
Enumerating objects: 6, done.
Counting objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 2.68 KiB | 2.68 MiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 0f11b1acbc6bdb39c6ea1fc83fa514db48551dfe
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 0f11b1acbc6bdb39c6ea1fc83fa514db48551dfe
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to bruh-bot-7869.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/bruh-bot-7869.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/bruh-bot-7869.git'
```

i have 2 files in the folder :-

main.py

rr.json

both are important

and in the Procfile :-

```
worker: python main.py
```

and requirements.txt :-

```
git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite
```

i have no idea what to do
please help!

Comment: i have googled it a lot of times but nothing worked for me :(

Comment: Do you have requirements.txt in your folder ?

Comment: yeah look at the question i have said that whats in my requiremnets.txt

Comment: Did you use pip freeze > requirements.txt ? Both procfile and requirements content are weird

Comment: Using my project as example, my Procfile is: web: gunicorn <app_name>.wsgi --log-file - and requirements are a list of all my imports

Comment: i found out whats causing the error , my python version is 2.7... and heroku only supports 3.9 above. i geuss its because of that

Comment: No, it's not because of your Python version (though that might become a problem soon and there aren't many good reasons to be using Python 2 in 2021). It's because your `requirements.txt` either doesn't have the correct name or isn't in the correct spot. Please [edit] your question and show a listing of your files.

Comment: well actually there are two version in my pc. one is python (2.7.16) and python3 (3.9.7)

Comment: then what should be in m requirements.txt 
i followed a youtube tutorial i have no idea what to do

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what was the problem
but i uploaded my files to github and connected heroku github to heroku
and deploying

i was 100% doing it wrong in requirement.txt

when i used pip3 freeze (Marrows in the comments told me that) and added all that to requirements.txt and uploaded to github.

and after that deployed the bot it all worked fine . Thanks :)